# Is it possible to calculate the volume of a object as its collision bounds?

Tags: game-engine, physics

Is it possible to calculate the volume of a object as its collision bounds
rather then the physical mesh? In the following scene, I have a stick of dynamite falling onto a field of cubes. It should destroy all cubes within the blast, but it is only destroying the ones touching the physical mesh.

Can this be done without changing the collision bound type from
Triangle Mesh to Convex hull or one of the other ones?

(Question stated again in blend file)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your object is sphere you can use the sphere collusion bound with the appropriate radius :

[image]

Here is [the WIKI entry about collusion bonds with example files](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Physics/Object/Static)

Comment: +1 for orange squares. not many other people use that color! Oh yah, and +1 for posting a good answer, that too